# remove focus from an HTML element on load

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [this](http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_375_tech_layer) theme for my website and I have customised its contents. I have added one more slide (fragment), on for login form. However, due to the username input field in this form, whenever the page loads, the focus shifts from home fragment to this username field and the page looks skewed. I tried adding a hidden field `hiddenfield` in the first home fragment and writing

```
<body onload="setfocus()">
```

where `setfocus()` is

```
function setfocus() {
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").focus();
}
```

but it didn't work.

In short, I need to remove the default focus from an inputbox on page and give it to a fragment. How to do this? Please help as I need to fix this issue immediately.

Comment: I don't think you can focus a field that's hidden. What element would you like to be in focus?

Comment: I dont want any particular element in focus, instead I think if I can disable the username textbox lose its focus while loading, the webpage will look proper

Comment: Also, changing the field type to `text` didn't work, the focus went to the username element only. Is that because the username element is after the hidden element in HTML code?

Comment: What browser are you using?  I'm not familiar with the browser giving focus to a certain input field by default.  That usually needs to be done explicitly with script.

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox. With BeatAlex's script, the browser gives momentary focus to the another text field but again it switches the focus to username

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle that demonstrates the behavior you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJQL9/)

Try this in either `<script>` tags or seperate `.js` file.

```
(function() {
   document.getElementById("hiddenfield").focus();
})();
```

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setFocus()
{
    document.getElementById("hiddenfield").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
<!-- stuff here -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the browser gives momentary focus to the another text field but again it switches the focus to username

Comment: I had not inserted the hiddenfield inside `<form> </form>`. Inserting it into a form worked along with above solution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the default focus to the input field, but if you add an `id` attr to the element you want to be at the top of the page, you should be able to navigate to it after the page loads.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        window.location.hash = '#divToFocus';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divToFocus">fasdfsdfsd</div>   
<form action="action">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
        E-mail: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
        Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try window.focus() instead of the hidden element